# how to pass unicode in asp.net web api to sql server database

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-web-api

I developed Asp.net WebAPI for Android app, now I want to store all information 
of the user from any language in  MSSQL Server Database. So, when we work on live API call from Mobile app through then they not working.

Error message:

> Returned Object reference Not Set Instance of an Object.

when I passing name = "Ķãushãl"

Thanks.

Comment: You'll need to post the code that is throwing the error.

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).